# Angular cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null DOM unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a form with a number of the input field and text-area, when a keyboard (enter) key event happens on the text-area need to evaluate the text-area is empty or not? If it is empty error displayed on the html mat-error tag. I would like to write the unit test case for this scenario. I can get the dom value using jquery in the browser console, but in the spec file can't able to get the DOM content.

spec.ts file

```
    it('should be display warning message', () => {
          const textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.need-access-shipping-address textarea')).nativeElement as HTMLTextAreaElement;
          textArea.value = "asd`";
          const event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress",{
            "key": "Enter"
          });
          textArea.dispatchEvent(event);
          fixture.detectChanges();
          const nameDisplay: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.need-access-shipping-address .mat-error')).nativeElement as HTMLElement;
          expect(nameDisplay.innerText).toBe('The format of the information entered is invalid');
    });
```

output getting as  `Expected: "The format of the information entered is invalid"
    Received: undefined`

Input `textArea.value = "asd~"` reg expression error

`textArea.value = "asd"` is a valid input

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the sample code of a unit test. Please note that the `text-area` and the display element both should have an `id` (I chose `text_area_1` and `name_display`) that makes it easier to query them using `By.css`.

```
it('pressing <enter> in empty text area should invalidate form', () => {

    // given
    const htmlTextArea: HTMLTextAreaElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#text_area_1')).nativeElement;
    htmlTextArea.value = 'asd~';
    htmlTextArea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // when
    const event: any = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.key = 'Enter';
    event.initEvent('keyup');
    htmlTextArea.dispatchEvent(event);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // then
    const nameDisplay: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#name_display')).nativeElement;
    expect(nameDisplay.innerText).toBe('The format of the information entered is invalid');
});
```

Comment: Sorry my component don't have `isFormValid()`. I updated my question please look into it.

Comment: @Rijo: I adapted the code in my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, here i found one mistake `#name_display` this selector will appear after sometime, it is not present always in the DOM tree. For that test execution will complete before the DOM is getting ready. So how to give some delay for the execution

Comment: There is no need to require id, but if you do you might as well use `By.id('the-id')` to select it.